# Creating a custom URL using variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, url

Hi I have been playing around with this for a while but no solution yet.

There are three parts to my code, the aim is to create a custom word to insert into a call for a url, so a specific kml file is loaded onto my webmap.

1. A function to generate a word by clicking a button on my website.(there are 6 other buttons that once clicked create a word)

   ```
   var pub = [];
   function myFunction7() { 
   pub.push("pub");
   ```
2. Once the words have been created, this step adds the variable to an array. The array will = the words needed to match the url.

   ```
   var url = [pub]
   ```

   So var url = bar if pub button is clicked.
3. I would like a new variable to = the words in the array that is generated after the user clicks the buttons.

   ```
   var name = url
   var src = "https://www.dropbox.com/"+name+".kml?dl=1";
   ```

The problem comes at step 3. Instead of loading the kml the map disappears and url to the kml file is not read so nothing is loaded. Buttons all work, I have tested up to step 2 by printing the result on the web page.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: it is a map layer but it would be treated the same as any other file you would like to load onto a website

Comment: Well if you cast array to string (which you are doing) you will get comma-separated values. Maby try to `var name = url.join('');` If you get the desired src the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: And the problem would come from the url that is malformed? Have you set name to "cafebar" before?

Comment: I have another piece of code to remove the commas. It seems that if I have var name = "bar" the layer loads

Comment: Yes the layer cafebar definitely exists, it is just not being read into the url line properly. If I change the var name ="cafebar" it works, but this is fixed text and would not respond to the buttons being selected, giving me no control to which layer is loaded

Comment: We have no way to know what `name` is , how code shown is used or what happens to request. Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. Please read [mcve]

Comment: interesting, but... in step 1 you say buttons to create a word, which I would expect to be a string, but your example shows an array (pub)

Comment: Would it make more sense to create a string instead of an array? I thought I was creating a string by putting the word into an array

Comment: you can use an array and join later., but more important do you want people to push buttons in a specific order, as that will be the order you build your array or string... or do you take care of the order... you also need to check all buttons are clicked, then run code to do the next step. Do you have a demo of your code?

Comment: I have arranged the var url in a certain order. After looking at it a bit more I think I have a better explanation of the problem: before any buttons are clicked, the pub and url variables will be empty. Once they are clicked the word is added correctly, but the var = name does not update with this information. Anyone know a way to solve this?

Comment: @Kar98k you asked this same question not even an hour ago, so I've flagged this as a duplicate.

Comment: @PatrickGoley no the other one is the duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your vars and their typeof? eg. using console.log

I think that, because pub is an array, then url is an array, then name is an array, then your src fails... expecting a string.

If you push only 1 string to pub then you could do:

```
var url = pub.toString();
```

or get the first element from pub:

```
var url = pub[0];
```

Of course you could do that later on, depending on the rest of your code, eg.

```
var name = url.toString();
var src = "https://www.dropbox.com/"+name.toString()+".kml?dl=1";
```

Comment: Thank you! This works in creating the correct url (as shown by the console log) but the file is still not loaded automatically onto the map. What does the 0 do in the var url = pub[0]?

Comment: it gets the first element from pub array... which is the string "pub" you pushed into it

Comment: how did you use the src string?

Comment: Is there a way to make the map reload its self after the button has been clicked? I think after the url is updated the map is not initialised with the new url

Comment: show code that sets the source attribute to the element... or show a demo of your page

Comment: function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.50275896, -0.11535645),
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

        loadKmlLayer(src, map);
}

Comment: function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(event) {
    var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
    var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
    testimonial.innerHTML = content;
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

Comment: Is it possible to send the script another way? I realise this is unclear but I am new to stack overflow!

Comment: Here is a js fiddle link to the code https://jsfiddle.net/kar98k/3p5r51nw/

Comment: ok... but what are you doing after var src="..." Do you call kml function or something?

Comment: after the var src I am intialising the map and loading the file and map

Comment: But that all happens when the web page loads... does that mean once I have clicked a button I need another function to initialize the map again?

Comment: I hoped you were gonna say you don't do anything with that src string haha. Sorry, I don't know much about that. Better search for updating map/ kml layer or something, or ask a new question

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, definitely closer to the solution than I was before